# Why doesn't this regex pattern work as intended?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, credit-card

I needed a regex pattern to catch any 16 digit string of numbers (each four number group separated by a hyphen) without any number being repeated more than 3 times, with or without hyphens in between.

So the pattern I wrote is

```
a=re.compile(r'(?!(\d)\-?\1\-?\1\-?\1)(^d{4}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}$)')
```

But the example "5133-3367-8912-3456" gets matched even when 3 is repeated 4 times. (What is the problem with the negative lookahead section?)

Comment: Do you need to use regex at all? It seems like this would be easier to write and understand using `str.split` and a `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookaheads only do the check at the position they are at, so in your case at the start of the string. If you want a lookahead to basically check the whole string, if a certain pattern can or can't be matched, you can add `.*` in front to make go deeper into the string.

In your case, you could change it to `r'(?!.*(\d)\-?\1\-?\1\-?\1)(^d{4}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}\-?\d{4}$)'`.

There is also no need to escape the minus at the position they are at and I would move the lookahead right after the `^`. I don't know how well python regexes are optimized, but that way the start of the string anchor is matched first (only 1 valid position) instead of checking the lookahead at any place just to fail the match at `^`. This would give `r'^(?!.*(\d)-?\1-?\1-?\1)(\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}-?\d{4}$)'`

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman It is a valid match and get's matched, see https://regex101.com/r/CYA4ng/1. Not sure why you doubt it?

Comment: I happen to be misunderstood the problem... And I blame the the confusion in the op's post for that ;)